# Update observable result

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I have an observable under my **tabs.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cartService.getCart(this.authId).subscribe(cart => {
    this.cart = cart;
  });
}
```

Where cartService.getCart under the file **cart.service.ts**

```
getCart(authId: string): Observable<Cart> {
  this.cartsCollection2 = this.afs.collection('carts', ref => ref.where('authId', '==', authId).where('status', '==', 'active'));
  this.cart = this.cartsCollection2.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => {
      return changes.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Cart;
        data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    })
  );
  return this.cart;
}
```

Once a payment has been made, I update the cart status to 'Paid' instead of 'active' which should update the result of the observable. In essence the cart in my tabs.ts should now be empty. How do I get updated the result?

Comment: Are `this.cart` in both the ngOnInit() and cartService same?

Comment: they're on a separate file. Updating my post now

Comment: when you subscribe getCart, what are the values that get emitted?

Comment: How do you update the cart status to `Paid`? Show us your code. You'll probably have to work with a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) in some way.